# jsoup Http permanent connection

Tags: http, networking, jsoup

I'm using Jsoup without any problem to scrape some websites. It works great and it's easy to use.

However, as I request the same site over and over, I'd like to use a HTTP permanent connection to avoid multiple TCP connection establishments and TCP connection terminations, to improve indexation performances.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Why you don't cache the documents instead?

Comment: No, because i need to see updated version of html pages. I request a lot of images too.

Comment: I see, unfortunately i don't think thats possible - without touching the code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [reuse the Jsoup connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13754518/reuse-the-jsoup-connection)